Typescript and stubbing/ mocking a cli extension
I'm working on a SF cli extension. As recommended, it's written in typescript. I'm writing unit tests.
I'm early on the learning curve for typescript and cli extensions for SF. I've been trying to crib from the boilerplate tests the generate creates, and looking at the tests in official salesforce repos, like this one: https://github.com/salesforcecli/plugin-org/blob/main/test/unit/force/org/sandboxCreate.test.ts
I've created a command: check:version and I'm trying to create tests for it, using this code:
it('should find files with disparate API versions', async () => {
    const packageDirectories: NamedPackageDir[] = [
      { name: 'package1', fullPath: 'path/to/package1' } as NamedPackageDir,
      { name: 'package2', fullPath: 'path/to/package2' } as NamedPackageDir,
    ];
    const ripGrepResults = ['path/to/file1.xml', 'path/to/file2.xml'];
    const fileContent1 = '<MetadataType><apiVersion>49.0</apiVersion></MetadataType>';
    const fileContent2 = '<MetadataType><apiVersion>50.0</apiVersion></MetadataType>';
    
    stubMethod($$.SANDBOX, SfProject.prototype, 'getPackageDirectories').returns(packageDirectories);
    stubMethod($$.SANDBOX, CheckVersion, 'ripGrepForAPITags').resolves(ripGrepResults);
    stubMethod($$.SANDBOX, fs, 'readFile')
      .withArgs('path/to/file1.xml', 'utf-8')
      .resolves(fileContent1)
      .withArgs('path/to/file2.xml', 'utf-8')
      .resolves(fileContent2);

    await CheckVersion.run([]);
    expect(sfCommandStubs.log).to.not.be.empty;
  });

However, I'm hitting some error messages I just don't understand. Specifically, ESLint errors saying the stubMethod lines are 'Unsafe call of an "any" typed value. (@Typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call)'
i've googled around a bit, and I understand that any is a special data type that basically voids typescripts type safety. What I don't understand is how to fix it? Especially since the SF tests I'm trying to learn from (first link) seem to be doing exactly this kind of work -- calling stubMethod in just this way. I've tried specifying .prototype and not specifying .prototype and ... no joy.
I feel like i'm missing something small but fundamental but I'm ... annoying close.
Help me typescript developers who also write Salesforce code. (all 3 of you),  you're my only hope.

All three of us? I'm surprised there's that many!
